# Django dynamically choose a foreign key relation model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, foreign-keys, generic-foreign-key

I have a `Comment` model that I've been using for the `News` model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=2048)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_edited_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.posted_by, self.news)
```

But now I have a `Materials` model and I want to have comments there too, but to use the same `Comments` model. Is there a way to dynamically choose the foreign key relation (`news = models.ForeignKey(...)` -> `news_or_material = ...` or something like this).

Of course I can write a separate model (`MaterialComment`), but I want to reuse my code.

Then in my viewset I should do something like this (I am using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)):

```
def create(self, request, news_pk=None):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    context = {'request': request, 'news': news}

    serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(
        context=context, data=request.data
    )
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

    return Response(
        serializer.validated_data,
        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
        headers=headers
    )
```

I need to turn `news_pk` parameter from the URL to a `pk` of `News` or `Material` and respectively `news_or_material = get_object_or_404(...)`

Comment: This is exactly what [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) are for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing this. Then it will wise to use GenericForeignKey provided by Django.

[Generic Foreign Key Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)